# Duplicate the record for the missing Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which we store the data as per company and its Year.

For Example

```
SELECT * FROM REITSCapitalAndFundSizes where companyid =4604
```

its return me the data of the company id = 2 and the contains the date .

For Example :

```
  CompanyID    REITSValue       CreatedOn       
    4604       500.0000         2015-06-09  
    4604       1633.0000        2018-03-19
```

As we can see the one row is for 2015 and the other row is for 2018 , The missing year between 2015 and 2018 is 2016 , 2017 , so I want to duplicate the row of 2015 for those 2 years (2016,2017).
Similarly after 2018 I have no rows so I want to duplicate the rows for 2019,20,21,22,2023 and the data will contain the record of 2018.

Expected Result :

```
CompanyID   REITSValue  CreatedOn
4604       500.0000    2015-06-09 00:00:00.000
4604       500.0000    2016-06-09 00:00:00.000
4604       500.0000    2017-06-09 00:00:00.000
4604       1633.0000   2018-03-19 00:00:00.000
4604       1633.0000   2019-03-19 00:00:00.000
4604       1633.0000   2020-03-19 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Outer join a calendar/year cte (or table.)

Comment: BTW, note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: please add the results are you expecting to see - you want the CreatedOn date duplicated?

Comment: @Stu check updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use recursion to fill in the blanks:

```
with Rcrse as
(
    select 
      CompanyID
    , REITSValue
    , CreatedOn
    , CreatedOnYr = year(CreatedOn)
    , StartFromCreatedOn = CreatedOn
    , RepeatUptoYr = 
          (select year(min(createdOn))-1
           from YrTable Nxt
           where Nxt.CompanyId = Ths.CompanyId
           and Nxt.CreatedOn > Ths.Createdon) 

    from YrTable Ths
    union all
    select 
          Rcrse.CompanyID
        , Rcrse.REITSValue
        , CreatedOn=dateadd(year, 1, Rcrse.CreatedOn)
        , CreatedOnYear = Rcrse.CreatedOnYr + 1
        , StartFromCreatedOn = Rcrse.StartFromCreatedOn
        , Rcrse.RepeatUpToYr
    from  Rcrse
    where Rcrse.CreatedOnYr < coalesce(Rcrse.RepeatUpToYr , 2023)
)
select * 
from Rcrse
order by CompanyId, CreatedOnYr
```

Without any hints, it would fill-in gaps of up-to hundred years; if you have larger gaps, use OPTION (MAXRECURSION 150) (adjusting the number).

Change 2023 to whatever year you want to complete up to (you can use year(getdate()) for current year).

Comment: Its duplicating the record for 1 year with each value 

for example for year 2019
4604 1633.0000 2018-03-19 00:00:00.000 2019 2018-03-19 00:00:00.000 NULL
4604 500.0000 2015-06-09 00:00:00.000 2019 2015-06-09 00:00:00.000 NULL

Comment: Adjusted (didn't realise you wanted to 'fake' the CreatedOn, I thoght CreatedOnYear would have been sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

It's admittedly a bit fiddly but here's a solution you can try.

Making use of a generated series of years (you could use a tally table, a calendar table or from SQL Server 2022 *generate_series*)

Using *lead* to pull the following date into the current row, we can cross join using *apply* with the generated dates and apply some logic to choose only required rows and manufacture the required new date value.

Depending on your requirements you can parameterise the year / range.

```
with n as (select n = 2014 + Row_Number() over (order by (select 1/0)) from(values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))n(n)),
comp as (select *, Lead(Year(CreatedOn),1,9999) over(order by CreatedOn) ny from t)

select CompanyId, REITSValue, DateFromParts(n, Month(CreatedOn), Day(CreatedOn)) CreatedOn
from comp
cross apply (
  select n
  from n
  where n >= Year(CreatedOn) and n < ny and n <= 2020
)x;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HBwoNlq6)

Comment: the number of years are dynamic , which means it can be start from 2014 or may be 2003 , i never know

Comment: You could use @parameters for the min and max years or determin them by using min() and max() on your data.

Comment: with n as (select n = 2010+ Row_Number() over (order by (select 1/0)) from(values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))n(n)),

this is giving me the range from 2011 to 2021

Comment: That's an example of how you generate a number series - if you need a larger range you can add elements to it or cross join it with itself or join with a calendar table/tally table etc for a larger range. The only range shown in your question is the 6 years from 2015-2020